# Constant "rendering" of off-screen elements in React app in chrome

Tags: performance, google-chrome, rendering

I am working on improving the performance of a complex React app with many components. The app loads user created "lists" (details unimportant) each item of which is rendered as a React component. If there are very many items in the list, performance begins to suffer.

If I run the Chrome profiler while not interacting with the app whatsoever, the performance profile looks like this:
[image: Chrome performance profiler output]

As you can see, during much of the idle time, the CPU appears close to maxed out "rendering", though almost no actual painting is occurring. This only occurs when the list is so long that it overflows the screen. Why does this happen and what is the cure?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly *why* Chrome behaves this way, but it appears that the more content is outside of the viewport, the more CPU cycles Chrome spends on this rendering process. It turns out this can be fixed by using the CSS property:

```
content-visibility: auto;
```

Basically what it does is tell Chrome not to bother doing the complex work of rendering elements with this property set if they are off-screen. It simply reserves space for them (in much the same way as `visibility: hidden` does). More information [here](https://css-tricks.com/more-on-content-visibility/).

In my case, as soon as this property was applied to the `<li>` elements in the list, the idle rendering process observed in the Chrome profiler almost completely stopped, and the app became *significantly* more responsive.

Note that if the height of the content is not set, you need to also set the `contain-intrinsic-size` property, which is your best guess at the vertical space the element will occupy. Chrome will use that until the element is scrolled into view, at which point it will work out the actual height.

One caveat: it seems that Chrome (and I assume other browsers that implement the property) will not recalculate the size of elements with this property set, even if they are on-screen. Thus I needed to set `content-visibility: visible` on those `<li>` elements where the height might need to change dynamically.

While that did the trick for me, I'd love to hear from anyone who knows why Chrome does so much work for offscreen elements even while the application is idle.

Comment: just a note. in my case "content-visibility: visible" broke css of element inside. I just wrapped element with div and added this css to the div. Suddenly some shadows, some other tiny things were gone. No matter if element is in viewport. I use ReactJs mui.com material ui components.